# Daily cron task 5 mins to 12am?

Tags: cron

How can I create a daily cron task 5 mins to 12am?

```
55 23 * * *
```

Not sure if this is correct or not. Any ideas?

Comment: This is daily at 23:55. What is the question?

Comment: Does this resource explain things better for you? https://www.maketecheasier.com/easy-way-to-schedule-and-automate-tasks-in-ubuntu/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=07012020

Comment: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) is a pretty good online tool for that kind of issues

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you have provided seems correct in regards to running daily at 11:55 PM.

You can find more in this [Cron Jobs Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: Noted for future posts. 
New user, first post, forgive my brevity on the format.

Comment: Now that I see your post again it seems fine! When I first saw it in the review I thought that it was link-only, but now I think it is a valid answer for the question. Sorry for that and welcome!